# How can I force an image to overlay on the title bar of my WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application that has an animated .gif used to briefly direct user attention. The .gif sits just outside of the bounds of my app's window, such that it is underneath, and covered by, the title bar.

See below:

[image]

Is there a way to force it to overlay on top? It's defined in XAML like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Margin="-5 -45 0 0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="/Resources/jump.gif" 
            Width="30" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

And it looks alright at design-time:

[image]

I tried using `DockPanel` instead of `Grid` as its container to no avail.

Lastly, is it possible to have it behave as though it was collapsed? That is, have it not take up horizontal space between the `ComboBox` and the Legend `Label`

Comment: Have you tried using `Panel.ZIndex` ?

Comment: Yeah it had no effect

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `Popup` so that it gets its own window handle.  This will also make it not take up space in the layout.  As an added bonus (or maybe headache) you will be able to position it with its `PlacementTarget` and `PlacementMode` properties, since it looks like that is what you are trying to do anyway.

Comment: The same also applies with ToolTip

Comment: WPF popups make me sad. I'll try after lunch

Answer (score 0):

I used a `Popup` and it is working quite well, but with some very little flickering.

```
<Window x:Name="Window1" .../>
      <Grid>
        <Button Content="Show" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button Content="Hide" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="265,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
        <Popup x:Name="Popup1" UseLayoutRounding="True" IsOpen="False" Placement="Top" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Window1}">
            <Image Source="C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\desert.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Width="75" Height="25"/>
        </Popup>
      </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code :

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Popup1.IsOpen = true;
}
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Popup1.IsOpen = false;
}

private void Window1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double offset = Popup1.HorizontalOffset;
    Popup1.HorizontalOffset = offset + 1;
    Popup1.HorizontalOffset = offset;
}
```

***Another approach (recommended) without Popup !***

XAML

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWindow.MainWindow" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="Window1" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
        Closing="Window1_Closing" Activated="Window1_Activated" LocationChanged="Window1_LocationChanged">    

        <Grid x:Name="root"/>

</Window>
```

TitleBarWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWindow.TitleBarWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Topmost="True"
        Title="TitleBarWindow" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Height="25" Width="200">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="g:\\jellyfish.jpg" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfWindow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        TitleBarWindow w = new TitleBarWindow();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            w.ShowActivated = true;
            w.Background = Brushes.Red;
        }

        private void Window1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Point pt = Window1.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
            w.Top = pt.Y - 27;
            w.Left = pt.X;
        }      

        private void Window1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Point pt = Window1.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
            w.Top = pt.Y-27;
            w.Left = pt.X;

            w.Show();
        }

        private void Window1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            w.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Second approach is very good, works smoothly.

Comment: I think this will work but `PointToScreen` throws an exception "This Visual is not connected to a PresentationSource"

Comment: it is working 100% fine without error. double check plz.

Comment: Are you calling `PointToScreen` in the xaml.cs for `Window1`?

Comment: @Brandon yes , Window1 is the name of the Window.

Comment: I assumed. It still throws the exception. I'm using MVVMLight which is somehow probably why...

Comment: @Brandon create simple application , i have posted xaml+code for that and see, we will improve it.

Comment: @Brandon Plz see updated answer which is very easy also see the animated output posted.